# OneHotEncoder raising NaN issue after SimpleImputer has been called already

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I have trouble understanding how pipelines are supposed to work in Sklearn. Following is an example using the titanic dataset.

```
data = pd.read_csv('datasets/train.csv')

cat_attribs = ["Embarked", "Cabin", "Ticket", "Name"]

num_pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy="median")),
    ])


str_pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent")),
    ])


full_pipeline = ColumnTransformer([
        ("num", num_pipeline, ["Pclass", "Age", "SibSp", "Parch", "Fare"]),
        ("str", str_pipeline, ["Cabin", "Sex"]),
        ("cat", OneHotEncoder(), ["Cabin"]),
    ])

full_pipeline.fit_transform(data)
```

I'd expect this to fill all missing `NaN` values (both in numeric and string) attributes, and then finally transform the `Cabin` attribute into a numerical one.

Instead the code ends up with the following error:

> ValueError: Input contains NaN. If I remove the line calling the
>   OneHotEncoder and printing the transformed array, there is no NaN
>   value.

Hence I wonder. How am I supposed to call `OneHotEncoder` in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend applying `OneHotEncoder` to all categorical variables. Hence make that as a seperate pipeline.

As it's a single step process for numerical columns, you can use the `ColumnTransformer` directly.

Try this!

```py
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer, make_column_transformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, make_pipeline

cat_preprocess = make_pipeline(SimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent"), OneHotEncoder())

ct = make_column_transformer([
        ("num", SimpleImputer(strategy="median"), ["Pclass", "Age", "SibSp", "Parch", "Fare"]),
        ("str", cat_preprocess, ["Cabin", "Sex"]),
    ])

pipeline = Pipeline([('preprocess', ct)])
```

Comment: Thanks. What does it mean that imputation and one hot  encoding  need to be sequental?

Comment: Applying your suggestion to data gives the following error "Specifying the columns using strings is only supported for pandas DataFrames"

Comment: Once imputation is carried out, one hot Encoding has to be appying on the imputed feature. That is what I mean by sequential.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up my previous answer, Can you try my updated answer?

Comment: If the solution had worked, kindly accept the answer  so that it can be helpful for others as well.